# VBA to change formula depending on the row the iteration is in

Tags: excel, vba, loops, excel-formula

I have a range of values in column G. I want to create a vba that changes the formula for each cell number depending on the row that is used in the iteration.

```
Sub the()

Dim c As Range

'//loop it
For Each c In Range(Range("G1"), Range("G1").End(xlDown))
    c.Formula = "=IF(C" & c & ">0,2,B" & c & "))"
    
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't understand the thumbs down

Comment: Not sure I follow that. Does each cell in G have a number in it? What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I know I got thumbs down, but I found the answer to my own question by myself. What I was trying to find out was how to put variables from other columns into a formula. Fo example, below I have 2*(E2) the formula entered into D2. The same iterations occur in D3, D4 etc.

It is hard to word this question properly.

```
Sub goth()
Dim c As Range
Dim a As Integer


'//loop it
For Each c In Range(Range("D2"), Range("D2").End(xlDown))
    a = c.Offset(0, 1)
    c.Formula = "=2*" & a
   
Next
End Sub
```